# getimagesize() when file name includes single quotes

Tags: php

Sample $file name: Last,_First (1942) 'Mel'.jpg

I get an error message when using getimagesize() whenever the filename includes single quotes. What's the solution? Here's what I have:

```
  $file = htmlspecialchars_decode($file, ENT_QUOTES);
  $filename = $dir.$file.'.jpg';
  $filename = str_replace(' ','_',$filename);
  list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);
```

I've tried replacing the ' with \' but that didn't help

Comment: What's the contents of `$file` before you run it through `htmlspecialchars_decode()`?

Comment: Have you considered just renaming the files by stripping out bad characters? Files names like above are just asking for trouble down the road and are bad practice to begin with. Last,_First (1942) 'Mel'.jpg can be made Last_First_1942_Mel.jpg using a PHP regex replace. Just a suggestion. =o)

Comment: $file = "Last, First (1942) 'Mel'"  (without the double-quote) before the first line.  There are 23,000+ files - about 6 gigs. More importantly, the file names are used for other info.